# Java program does not run after build

Tags: java, netbeans, build, nullpointerexception

I programmed a tool with NetBeans, and it is working when I run it within the IDE. I've put all source files I need for the Tool into the `resources` folder.

After Build and Clean the program didn't start, it threw an Exception --> File not found.

I used relative paths to use the data I need, for example like this:

```
view.jIconRed1.setIcon(
  new javax.swing.ImageIcon(
    getClass().getResource("/usaTrafficResearchTool/resources/Icons/CheckMark22x20.png")));
```

And it's working fine, until I build it. After I tried a few things Clean and Build isn't even working anymore:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Update:

Thank you all for your help!! Aprreciate that.

Here's the Stacktrace (the "first" one, it can't find the .txt which it should read from):

```
C:\Users\rkryp_000>java -jar "D:\Raffa\Dokumente\USATrafficTool_V2.1\USATrafficLawResearchTool\dist\USATrafficLawResearchTool.jar"

Sep 24, 2015 12:53:32 PM presenter.Presenter getStateLinesFromTxt
SCHWERWIEGEND: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException:        file:\D:\Raffa\Dokumente\USATrafficTool_V2.1\USATrafficLawResearchTool\dist\USATrafficLawResearchTool.jar!\usaTrafficResearchTool\resources\Data\stateResources.txt
(Die Syntax f³r den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datentrõgerbezeichnung ist falsch)
```

(in english: the syntax for the filename, foldername or the name of the drive is wrong.)

```
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at presenter.Presenter.getStateLinesFromTxt(Presenter.java:89)
    at presenter.Presenter.setStateList(Presenter.java:63)
    at presenter.Presenter.main(Presenter.java:194)
```

Here is what my Filereader looks like:

```
private static void setStateList() throws URISyntaxException {
    URL fileNameAsUrl = MainScreen.class.getClassLoader().getResource("usaTrafficResearchTool/resources/Data/stateResources.txt");


private static List getStateLinesFromTxt(URL fileNameAsUrl) {
    List array = new List();
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileNameAsUrl.getFile())));
    String line;
```

I checked if the .jar file is packed correctly, and it seems so, the path for the .txt file is actually correct.

Thank you for your support so far!!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the file in the classpath, so the image is not correctly packaged into the jar file.

Open the jar file, e.g. using WinZip, to see if the file is there. If not, fix the build script.

Comment: I opened the file and everything was included, so I don't know why it says it can't find the file under the given path...

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a relative path Java looks for the file relative to where it is currently running, therefore Java might find the file when you run it inside the IDE but not when you try to run it in you webserver.
The **getClass().getResource(...)** looks for the file relative to the classpath, meaning the place where all the compiled .class files is located inside the jar.

Make sure that the file is included in the jar, if not there is probably an option for it in the IDE, and make sure the path looks the same inside the jar as it does from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `CheckMark22x20.png` file in `src/resources/Icons/` (`src/resources/Icons/CheckMark22x20.png`) folder and change the code to

```
view.jIconRed1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/Icons/CheckMark22x20.png")));
```

Now clean and build the jar file. It should work without any problems.